# Unable to open facebook chat window using Selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to open a chat window with a friend named "Fname Lname" on facebook but Python throws an error. Strange thing is, the same code in the same sequence works perfectly fine on IDLE but doesn't when run through a script file.

```
#! python3
#sends a facebook message to a friend after logging in

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

fb=webdriver.Chrome()

fb.get('https://www.facebook.com')
fb.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('example@gmail.com')
fb.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('somepasswd'+Keys.ENTER)
fb.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)

fb.find_element_by_name("mercurymessages").click()
fb.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Fname Lname")]').click()
fb.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="combobox"]').send_keys("random text"+Keys.ENTER)
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),"Fname Lname")]"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait until the name loaded in list

Use below code

```
WebDriverWait(fb, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Fname Lname')]")))
```

Complete Code Will be :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
fb=webdriver.Chrome()

fb.get('https://www.facebook.com')
fb.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('example@gmail.com')
fb.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('somepasswd'+Keys.ENTER)
fb.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)

fb.find_element_by_name("mercurymessages").click()
WebDriverWait(fb, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Fname Lname')]")))
fb.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Fname Lname")]').click()
fb.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="combobox"]').send_keys("random text"+Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: thank you.. worked like a charm.. but can you explain what does "expected_conditions" do ?

Comment: It will wait until your element get clickable within given time. If not fulfill the given condition within the timeframe then it throw the exception. In your case the it takes some time to load the friend list so here you have to wait until the name get clickable if it become then perform click